# Building KVM images

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization, 16.04, qcow2

What is the best way to build Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 images for KVM?

Until now, I have been using `vmbuilder` for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but it seems it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-vm-builder` seems to still be the standard way to do it.